# Unable to get values in C# Structure from C++

Tags: c#, c++

There is a nested structure which contains another structure in it. The C++ function takes a Structure pointer.  I am calling this C++ function from C# code.

I create an object from the structure and pass it to the C++ code as an `out parameter`. This C++ function actually calls another function from a `dll` and I am able to get the value in C++ but when it comes to C#, I am not able to get the value.

Can anyone help me in getting the structure values in C#?

Regards,
Balaji

Comment: You might show some code of what you have done try to point out where your trouble is, that will help others understand your problem. You might also tell how you interface between C++ and C#. Managed C++, COM or PInvoke?

Comment: One thing to check would be to ensure you've set the StructLayout attribute correctly. At a minimum, you should post the C++ and C# struct definitions, as well as indicate what compiler & architecture you're compiling your C++ with.